# How to unit test non-public logic

Tags: oop, unit-testing, tdd

In some cases unit testing can be really difficult. Normally people say to only test your public API. But in some cases this is just not possible. If your public API depends on files or databases you can't unit test properly. So what do you do?

Because it's my first time TDD-ing, I'm trying to find "my style" for unit testing, since it seems there is just not the one way to do so. I found two approaches on this problem, that aren't flawless at all. On the one hand, you could try to friend your assemblies and test the features that are internal. On the other hand, you could implement interfaces (only for the purpose of unit testing) and create fake objects within your unit tests. This approach looks quite nice first but becomes more ugly as you try to transport data using these fakes.

Is there any "good" solution to this problem? Which of those is less flawed? Or is there even a third approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to test a class with private methods using JUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a couple of false starts in TDD, grappling with this exact same problem. For me the breakthrough came when I realized what my mentor meant when he said : "We don't want to test the framework." (In our case that was the .Net framework).

In your case it sounds as if you have some business logic that interfaces to files and databases. What I would do is to abstract the file and database logic in the thinnest layers possible. You can then use Mock (of fakes or stubs) to simulate the file and database layers. This will allow you to test scenarios like if-my-database-returns-this-kind-of-information-does-my-business-logic-handle-it-correctly? Likewise for file access you can test the code that figures out which file in which path to open and you can test that your logic would be able to pull apart the contents of any given file correctly and able to use it correctly.

If for example your file access layer consists of a single function that takes a path name and a file name and returns the contents of the file in a long string then you don't really need to test it because essentially you are making a single call to the framework/OS and there is not a lot that can go wrong there.

At the moment I am working on a system that wraps our database as a bunch of functions that return lists of POCO's. Easy to understand for the business layer and easy to simulate via mocks.

Working this way takes some getting used to but it is absolutely byoo-ti-full once it clicks in your mind.

Finally, from your question I guess that you are working with legacy code and trying to do TDD for a new component. This is quite a bit harder than doing TDD on a completely new development. If it is at all possible, try to do your first TDD attempts on new (or well isolated) systems. Once you have learnt the mechanics it would be a lot easier to introduce partially TDD'd bits to legacy systems.

Answer (score 2):

```
If your public API depends on files or databases you can't unit test properly. So what do you do?
```

There is an abstraction level that can be used.

- IFileSystem/ IFileStorage (for files)
- IRepository/ IDataStorage (for databases)

Since this level is very thin its integration tests will be easy to write and maintain. All other code will be unit-test friendly because it is easy to mock interaction with filesystem and database.

```
On the one hand, you could try to friend your assemblies and test the features that are internal.
```

People face this problem when their classes violates [single responsibility principle  (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [dependency injection (DI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) is not used.

There is a good rule that classes should be tested via their public methods/properties only. If internal methods are used by others then it is acceptable to test them. Private or protected methods should not be made internal because of testing.

```
On the other hand, you could implement interfaces (only for the purpose of unit testing) and create fake objects within your unit tests.
```

Yes, interfaces are easy to mock because of limitations of mocking frameworks.
If you can create an instance (fake/stub) of a type then your dependency should not implement an interface.

Sometimes people use interfaces for their domain entities but I do not support them.

To simplify working with fakes there are two patterns used:

1. [Object Mother](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html)
2. [Test Data Builder](http://nat.truemesh.com/archives/000714.html)

When I started writing unit tests I started with 'Object Mother'. Now I am using 'Test Data Builder's.

There are a lot of good ideas that can help you in the book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) by Michael Feathers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the hard stuff get in your way... If it's inherently hard to test due to db or file integration, just ignore it for the moment. Most likely you can refactor that hard to test stuff into easier to test stuff using mocks with Dependency Injection etc... Until then, test the easy stuff and get a good unit test suite built up... when you do the refactoring of the hard to test stuff, you will have a much higher confidence interval that it's not breaking anything else... And refactoring to make something more easily testable IS a good reason to refactor...